# Multiple javascript elements on one page?

Tags: javascript

I know pretty much no javascript, and I just need to do something for an art class. Basically, I want to have multiple images on the same page that toggle between 3 images each.

This is the script:

```
 var images = ["images/image1.png", "images/image2.jpg", "images/image3.jpg"];
 var clicks = 0;

 $(document).ready(start);

 function start(){
     $("#panel_1").click(changeImage);
 }

 function changeImage(){
     clicks++;
     img = images[clicks % images.length];
     $("#panel_1").attr("src", img);
 }
```

And here's the HTML:

```
 <div id="panel1">
 <a href="#">
    <img id="panel_1" border="0" src="images/SquirrelFull.jpg" width="230px" height="230px"/>
 </a>
 </div>
```

Now I want all of this, but a second one, to make panel_2 (and 3, 4, 5, etc.)

Comment: just do it, create another panel, with different ID, create another img array.
In a second some noob will do it for u, or u can show us what you tried, and did not work, although a forum is more appropriate for such questions.

Comment: When I add another panel, I don't know how to make different var images so that each image toggles with 3 different images. So, when I do it, panel_1 and panel_2 toggles through the same 6 images.

Comment: I tried going with var images1, var images2 and var clicks1 and var clicks2, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: update the question with the code u tried, panel_1 and panel_2 example.